# Redis Server Startup with config

Tags: redis, master-slave

When I tried to start redis server with config, the server is not coming up. Its struck up in the below step

```
C:\Redis-x64-2.8.2400> redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf
```

When I start without `config file`, the server starts. Please let me know if I'm missing anything here. `TIA`

Comment: Can you add the configuration file content? What is the meaning of 'struck up' what exactly happen?

Comment: Now it is working fine when I downloaded 3.0.504. Thank You